# How would you say "to time a race"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras

Online translators aren't identifying time as a verb for some reason and I want to know how to say for example:

> You have to run the race again. I forgot to **time** it.

Is `medir` the appropriate verb?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed *medir* is the common verb:

> Tienes que repetir la carrera, se me olvidó medir<sub>(te)</sub> el tiempo

*El tiempo* is often needed because *medir* by itself just means *to measure* and could equally apply to the length of the race.  It is common to see with an indirect object in the sense of "to time [someone]".  As mentioned in the comments, in some countries such as Argentina and Chile, *tomar<sub>(le)</sub> tiempo* may be used instead of *medir<sub>(le)</sub> el tiempo*:

> Tienes que repetir la carrera, se me olvidó tomarte<sub>(te)</sub> el tiempo

Unfortunately, because both expressions can mean something else in different contexts (the former, meaning *to take time [to do something]*, the latter, *to measure the weather*), I can't really gauge exact proportions of usage or get a feel for any deeper geographic variance.

You also have a more technical option which won't be used as much in speech, but exists nonetheless:

> **[cronometrar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BMBrgB4)**. 1. *tr.* Medir con el cronómetro el tiempo de algo.

It's similar to English *to clock* someone (in the time, not speed, sense), and is formed on a similar base, *cronómetro* (which is more commonly used than *chronometer* in English and refers to most any clock that measures precise time as opposed to displaying the current time)

Comment: In Argentina, "medir" el tiempo sounds really weird. People say "tomar" el tiempo.

Comment: @martinArgerami ¿allí lo usarían de la misma forma (es decir, más comúnmente como «tomarte el tiempo» que como «tomar el tiempo»)?

Comment: Sí, en Argentina se les toma el tiempo a los corredores.

Comment: En Chile también te tomas el tiempo.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta. @Rodrigo

Comment: Well, I've always used "cronometrar", since I was a kid, and my children use it too ("conométrame (sic) lo que tardo en dar una vuelta al parque"), so I don't think it's so uncommon.